# ErrorProvider for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, errorprovider

What should I use in WPF instead WinForms ErrorProvider control to show error messages?

I have looked at codeplex and at http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/, and I didn't see anything similar.

Can anyone suggest a good WPF replacement to me?

**UPDATE:**

Let's take the standard approach that is applied [in the codeproject article on WPF validation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation):

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Name">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ExceptionValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

This complies with .net 3 rules. In .net 4, Expression Blend Generates code like this:

```
<TextBox Margin="48,72,63,201" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Input, ElementName=Window, FallbackValue=1+1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
```

and trying to add Binding.ValidationRules inside this TextBox crashes the code.

What is the proper syntax of adding validation in .net 4?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Provider in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701126/error-provider-in-wpf)

Comment: the question is 3 years old. May be something has changed since

Comment: I think the link provided in that answer is still probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by yourself. look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817039/wpf-validationerror-summary-behavior-control) to see what i have done.

[image]

Comment: The posted link is broken - can you please share some of the code used for this?

Comment: The link is broken, it is a pitty - the answer is therefore not helpful although the question still is topical.